# What are the advantages of mutilating someone, rather than just killing them?

Tags: manhunt

In Manhunt, I've just finished the tutorial level, where I am shown that, during a stealth kill, the longer I hold the action button for, the more gruesome the attack becomes.

Now, there are several *disadvantages* to this:

- Performing a fully-fledged mutilation takes a good 5-10 seconds, during which time the victim is likely to turn around, or I am likely to be spotted by another Hunter.
- The more gruesome the attack, the more noise it makes, so, if there is a Hunter with friends nearby, and I brutally murder him, they will hear and come to kill me.

So, I am left wondering: what is the incentive to brutally murder someone in this game?

Comment: Wait, IRL or....?

Comment: I love the "Don't include the game name in the question title" policy. And I love the Hot Network Questions sidebar.

Comment: It does produce some awesome question titles, but unless the question is leaning toward being that awesome, I always prefer the game's name in the title (or at least a short version of it - there's need to say "How do I X in The Elder Scrolls V:  Skyrim?"), especially over on RPG.SE.  Several times I've started writing an answer only to discover that the assumed game (especially when following a related question link from that game) isn't the game the question is about.

Comment: The level of execution has no effect on produced sound, the weapon class does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more brutal your kills, the higher your ranking at the end of a level. Reaching a 5-star rank requires you to achieve a set number of brutal executions.

Taken from the game's [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhunt_%28video_game%29):

> At the end of each scene, the player is graded based on their performance, and awarded one to five stars. Unlockable content becomes available only when the player achieves three or more stars on a certain number of levels. On normal difficulty (called "Fetish"), the player can earn only four stars; one is awarded for completing the scene under a certain amount of time, and one to three stars are awarded based on the brutality of the executions carried out during the scene. On hard difficulty (called "Hardcore"), the player is graded out of five stars; one for speed, one to three for brutality and one for simply completing the scene. To gain the maximum number of stars, a set number of brutal executions must be carried out over the course of each scene; face-to-face fighting does not award stars. [[original source, IGN]](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/manhunt/Basics)